# Why does my logo not appear in the Bootstrap navbar when using Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, navbar, bootstrap-5

I'm working on Ruby on Rails and I'm trying to put a logo.png image in a bootstrap navbar.
so i used this code in app/views/home/_header.html.erb

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg bg-primary " data-bs-theme="dark"> 
  <div class="container-fluid">
   <!-- <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Estrutecnia</a> -->
 <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
      <img src="logo.png" alt="Estrutecnia" width="30" height="24">
    </a>


    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
      <ul class="navbar-nav me-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item dropdown">
          <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
            Dropdown
          </a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a></li>
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a></li>
            <li><hr class="dropdown-divider"></li>
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link disabled">Disabled</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <form class="d-flex" role="search">
        <input class="form-control me-2" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
        <button class="btn btn-outline-success" type="submit">Search</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>

</nav>
```

The problem is that the logo doesn't appear, look at the navbar
[image: navbar not displaying logo]

And the next errors display

```
Started GET "/logo.png" for 127.0.0.1 at 2023-06-02 20:05:47 -0500

ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/logo.png"):
```

I tried to put the logo.png file in the root directory that I guess is the folder where the Gemfile and the README.md files are.
I expect that the logo.png appears at the navbar, but a brocken file icon appears at the left side of the navbar, like described in the image above.

Comment: it tells you, your not giving it a path to your logo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Images are normally placed in the app/assets/images directory.

When you render a view using the ActionView image_tag helper, Rails automatically populates the image source for you:

```rb
image_tag('logo.png')
# => <img src='/assets/icon.png>
```

This would be the idiomatic way to handle images in Rails, but of course there's nothing that prevents you from including `<image src='/assets/icon.png'>` in your markup